# Update php 5.3.3 to 5.3.19 in CentOS 6.3

Tags: php, centos6

I have a production server running several applications with apache and php 5.3.3 and I wish to update the PHP version to 5.3.19 or higher (although a lower version like 5.3.12 would do the honors).

Is there a way to accomplish this?
Is it safe for existing applications?

Thanks for any help or recommendation

Comment: "and I wish" --- is there something technical behind this "wish"? If so - what is it? From what you've said you can be sure it's the terrible idea because: 1. You probably don't know Centos well 2. You don't know php at all. These 2 will lead to a catastrophe without doubts.

Comment: 1st u must check which php higher version its your script supported.